# Highlight gaps in the Carotid-Kundalini Fractal

Tags: plotting, graphics, fractals

> **Gaps in Fractal Land occur whenever**
>   $$x\cos^{-1}x=2\pi\frac{p}{q}$$
>   **for** $p$ **and** $q$  **realatively prime integers.At such points** $x$, **the functions assume the** $⌈(q+1)/2⌉$ **values** $\cos(2\pi/q)$ **for** $r=0,1,..., \lfloor q/2\rfloor$.

**How can I highlight gaps in the fractal land by using *Mathematica*?**

```
list = Table[Cos[n x ArcCos[x]], {n, 1, 25}];

Plot[list, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001],PlotPoints -> 150, 
AspectRatio -> 1/3,ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], 
Background -> Lighter[Black, 0.1], 
PlotLabel ->Text[Style["Fractal Valley      Gaussian Mountain     Oscillation Land", 
Red,24, Italic, Magnification -> 1.8], Background -> LightBlue]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[list, {x, -1, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001], 
PlotPoints -> 150, AspectRatio -> 1/3, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], 
Background -> Lighter[Black, 0.1],PlotLabel -> 
Text[Style["Fractal Valley", Red, 24, Italic, Magnification -> 2]]]
```

[image]

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @MarcoB I want to do something like [this](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/pickover/carotid-clean.jpg)